# in my webpages some characters changed when uploaded on host but fine in local Asp.net MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented a webpage with ASP.net MVC. the problem is that when I type foreign languages special characters like `Spätes Frühstück` in German language it does not show it and it changed to something else `SpÃ¤tes FrÃ¼hstÃ¼ck` .

I am not sure why this happened and I do not know I should put which codes of the project. and the amazing part is that it works fine when I check it offline in local host, but it show like this when it goes on domain. may it be the server provider problem?

I really appreciate any help. thank you

Comment: Do you try to copy paste the text :))

Comment: yes I do, I copied from google translate . should not ? @Tomato32

Comment: We had some pretty similar issues couple of months back. the problem was with the fonts that we ware used in local which was differ from server. @nedaDerakhshesh

Comment: @ZiaulKabirFahad I will change the fonts and check again but it does not seems the problem is in CSS. becuase when I get inspect element it shows this again SpÃ¤tes FrÃ¼hstÃ¼ck in the html

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12108900/6311571) I think might be helpful to you

Comment: @ZiaulKabirFahad I checked the link, but I am not sure how to do it exactly. my problem is that why it is fine in local offline?

Comment: @ZiaulKabirFahad what is cassete exactly? I do not have any settings for buffer and I dont know what is cassete

Comment: I found the answer in this link and it was very helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283697/one-aspx-page-to-have-utf-8-encoding/33283743?noredirect=1#comment92202713_33283743

Comment: I found the answer in this link and it was very helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283697/one-aspx-page-to-have-utf-8-encoding/33283743?noredirect=1#comment92202713_33283743